# phonegap 3.2 camera.getPicture not showing the camera view

Tags: javascript, ios, backbone.js, cordova, cordova-3

When I try navigator.camera.getPicture the native camera view is not showing. To make it appear I have to reopen the app or swipe up (it opens Control Center and the camera view).
I am using Backbone.js and Ratchet.

My code:

```
cameraClickHandler: function () {

       navigator.camera.getPicture(this.cameraSuccess, this.cameraFail,
                     quality: 75,
                     correctOrientation: true,
                     destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                     saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
                     sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                     encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                     targetWidth: 600,
                     targetHeight: 600
                   }
                 );
           }
```

the error I get:

```
THREAD WARNING: ['Camera'] took '613.226807' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.

Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
```

Any ideas?